# 'catch' from within MonadIO

Tags: haskell, exception

I have a MonadIO instance in my program and I want to throw/catch exceptions(from `Control.Exception` module in base package) from withing that MonadIO.

A quick Google search returned lots of discussions(dating 2003) and complex soulutions(like implementing MonadControlIO, MonadBase etc. instances), I was wondering if there is an easy/accepted/widely-used solution for that,

If there is not, what would be a nice solution for this problem? As far as I can see there are several packages in Hackage addressing this problem, which one should I use?

(as an aside, recommended readings about why we don't have `catch` in `MonadIO` would also be appreciated)

Thanks,

---

EDIT: So Thomas's answer works fine but I also wondering what are other alternatives, my main purpose to use `IO` exceptions instead of `ErrorT` was performance, and I gain some performance after `Control.Monad.IO.Control` (443389 ticks vs. 318552 ticks), are there any better alternatives to `Control.Monad.IO.Control`?

Comment: One solution is to just add an extra class constraint: [MonadCatchIO](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadCatchIO-transformers/0.3.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-CatchIO.html).  Another solution is to use monad-control.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, how can I implement `catch` in MonadCatchIO for my monad stack?

Comment: @sinan: Any example code will really help

Comment: @Ankur, you can think any `newtype MyMonad = MyMonad { unwrapMyMonad = StateT _ IO _ }`

Comment: @sinan That depends on your monad stack, for which you haven't provided examples, but `StateT` and other common transformers [already have instance defined](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadCatchIO-transformers/0.3.0.0/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-CatchIO.html) which you can use as examples.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, thanks, turns out my monad stack already an instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two common solutions: `monad-control` and `MonadCatchIO-transformers`. And both of them has a set of disadvantages. For example with `monad-control` you always need to define `MonadBaseControl` manually because it can't be derived. `MonadCatchIO-transformers` is not under development now, doesn't works with GHC 7.7, and according to [this issue](https://github.com/ekmett/lens/issues/301) "Looks like the author of MonadCatchIO-transformers is about to deprecate the package.".

But some weeks ago new [exceptions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions) packages was released. It has better(more similar to `Control.Exception`) API than `MonadCatchIO-transformers`, supports pure exceptions and it's `mtl` friendly.

---

Update:

I did a benchmark between `lifted-base` that uses `monad-control` and `exceptions`, I use [this](https://github.com/basvandijk/lifted-base/blob/master/bench/bench.hs) benchmark and just replace `monad-peel` with `exceptions`. Result:

```
| benchmark | exceptions | lifted-base |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| bracket   | 148.38 ns  | 182.28 ns   |
| bracket_  | 47.30 ns   | 112.37 ns   |
| catch     | 62.85 ns   | 156.30 ns   |
| try       | 54.70 ns   | 77.84 ns    |
```

Deviation is about several ns.